# Incomplete Integration in Area

Tags: functions, numerical-integration

```
Area[2 Sqrt[(1 - p^2)^2 - r^2], {p, 0, 1}, {r, 0, 1 - p^2}]
```

is able to perform only the integral over `r`, leaving the integral over `p` to be performed.  I can work around this by append a second command,

```
NIntegrate[%[[1]], %[[2]]]
```

to produce a numerical answer.  Do any undocumented `Area` options exist to perform the total calculation without such a work-around?  The obvious `Method -> "NIntegrate"` does not work in this instance.

Comment: The "NIntegrate" method should work here.  It's being overly strictly in how it's testing the endpoints.  I will file a bug and try to fix this for the next release.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Area results in a special function output with an assumption. You can force the evaluation simply by  appending //N

```
Area[2 Sqrt[(1 - p^2)^2 - r^2], {p, 0, 1}, {r, 0, 1 - p^2}]
```

(* Integrate[-(-1 + p^2) Sqrt[1 + 16 p^2] EllipticE[-(3/(1 + 16 p^2))], {p, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> 0 < 1 - p^2] *)

```
Area[2 Sqrt[(1 - p^2)^2 - r^2], {p, 0, 1}, {r, 0, 1 - p^2}] // N
```

-> 2.38377

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
Options[NArea] = Options[NIntegrate];

NArea[R__, ops:OptionsPattern[]] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{Integrate}, 
  Unprotect[Integrate];
  Integrate[Shortest[e__], r___Rule] := NIntegrate[e, ops]; 
  Area[R]
]

NArea[2 Sqrt[(1 - p^2)^2 - r^2], {p, 0, 1}, {r, 0, 1 - p^2}]
```

> ```
> 2.38377
> ```